# configure-like for CMake

Tags: cmake, autotools

G'day.

Is there a tool which provides autoconf-like configure interface to CMake?  eg instead of

```
cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=mpicc
```

invoke same command via

```
./configure CC=mpicc
```

Comment: @arrowdodger I prefer configure style.

Comment: Are you wanting to put functionality in a configure script for a project that uses Cmake?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I just want a script to pass configure like options to cmake, if such tool exists

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the call to cmake in the configure script (from OpenSceneGraph):

```
openscenegraph$ cat ./configure 
cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release $@
```

Be aware that this will perform an "in-source" build. You can pass build variables via the usual -DVARNAME=VALUE, e.g.:

```
./configure -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=On
```

Comment: Wow that's just plain ugly. Since users often take that "configure" means autoconf, they will be terribly disappointed if it does not support all the options. Starting with --prefix, for one.

Comment: @jørgensen yes, that's pretty much what I want - `--prefix, --with-, --enable`, etc

Comment: You can map the various configure options to `-DVAR:TYPE=Value` in the script but that gets silly fast. Other than that I am not aware of any tool that interprets CMakeLists.txt files and generates autoconf files.

Answer (score 0):

This [github project](https://github.com/nemequ/configure-cmake) provides a `configure` script that understands and translates between a cmake project and a standard `autotools` `configure` including support for `--prefix` and `--enable`

It takes a little bit to grok, but I believe its the closest solution to what you're expecting.